# Display while using loop uncertain of certain things

Tags: shell, while-loop

i have this while loop below which i am trying to get the results listed below. The purpose of the loop is to go through the BookDB.txt and find all patterns matching either the Title or Author and after it is found the loop will print it out but currently my issue is that i am trying to insert a line before the list of all the matching pattern called "Number of Records Found: X".

```
number of records found: X
Title,Author,Price,QtyAvailable,QtySold
```

i am not sure of where to put the line to get the record, because if i put it inside the loop it will become duplicated and i am trying to avoid duplicating the number of records found line

```
#matching item 1     
number of records found: X
Title,Author,Price,QtyAvailable,QtySold

#matching item 2
number of records found: X
Title,Author,Price,QtyAvailable,QtySold
```

but i am uncertain of how i should modify my code to do it. need help please, the input of the file is

```
 Title:Author:Price:QtyAvailable:QtySold


function search_book
 {
echo "Enter Title: "
read title_r
echo "Enter Author: "
read author_r
while read -r result
do
title=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 1 -d ":")
author=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 2 -d ":")
price=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 3 -d ":")
qty_ava=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 4 -d":")
qty_sold=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 5 -d ":")
if echo "$title" | grep -iq "$title_r" && echo "$author" | grep -iq "$author_r";
then
record=$(grep -io "$title" BookDB.txt | sort | uniq -c)
echo -e "$title,$author,$price,$qty_ava,$qty_sold"      
fi  
done < ./BookDB.txt
echo ""
echo "Number of records found: " $record | cut -f1-6 -d" "
echo ""

  }
```

Comment: What about this isn't working? Is the output wrong? Are you getting an error? What are you trying to change exactly?

Comment: Hi i am trying to change it so that the record display will come before the title and other details first but i am unsure how to do so because if i put in the loop the record line will have duplicates and i only want 1 line showing the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u just need to put the record line before the while loop and echo the record first then the loop will run through the program , and display your list of matching pattern without any duplicate of record

```
function search_book
{
   echo "Enter Title: "
   read title_r
   echo "Enter Author: "
   read author_r
   record=$(grep -io "$title_r" BookDB.txt | sort | uniq -c)
   echo "Number of records found: " $record | cut -f1-6 -d" "
   while read -r result
   do
   title=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 1 -d ":")
   author=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 2 -d ":")
   price=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 3 -d ":")
   qty_ava=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 4 -d":")
   qty_sold=$(echo "$result" | cut -f 5 -d ":")
   if echo "$title" | grep -iq "$title_r" && echo "$author" | grep -iq "$author_r";
   then
   #record=$(grep -io "$title" BookDB.txt | sort | uniq -c)
   echo -e "$title,$author,"\$"$price,$qty_ava,$qty_sold"
   fi   
   done < ./BookDB.txt
   echo ""
   #echo "Number of records found: " $record | cut -f1-6 -d" "
   echo ""
   main_menu

}
```

Comment: oh i see, careless mistake of me